# AS3 - why are the gestures so unresponsive using Flash / AIR

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, air, gesture

I have created 3 or 4 android games with Flash and AIR and the gestures swipe and pan are just so irresponsive it's impossible to use them. for example i am trying to do slider with a pan gesture and it misses the gesture at least 1 every 3 times.
same for swipe, i have a game with things falling and had to swipe to push them back up a bit but it was a 1 in 5 success rate !

is anyone out there using these gestures with Flash / AIR (on Samsung S2) and did you make it work ?

thanks !

Edualc

Comment: Have you run anything else on your Samsung SII to compare? Here's a [good benchmark from Starling](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.dustunited.StarlingBenchmark&hl=en) that you should run to see whether Flash's sw rendering is slow or the hardware itself.

Answer (score 1):

Gestures have a very high overhead for each listener. If you have multiple gesture listeners running at the same time, each listener will run tests `ON_ENTER_FRAME` (anecdotal it seems) and the issue becomes multiplied. If I ever have multiple objects on the stage that all require the same gesture, I add the listener to the stage, then test to see if the Event.target is one of my objects. This practice also allows better re-usability of code.

Something like:

```
Stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, swipped);
Stage.mouseChildren = false;
function swipped(e:TransformGestureEvent):void {
    if(array_of_objects.indexOf(e.target)) {
        Stage.removeChild(e.target);
    }
}
```

This works best if all your falling object are within one wrapper container so you don't have to remove mouse events from all children of the stage, just children of the wrapper.

If you can't access the stage from your code's location (within a class) you can use `DisplayObject.Stage.addEventListener...`